# Is it possible to use cyrillic symbols in Lumen(by Laravel)?

Tags: php, laravel, utf-8, lumen, cyrillic

The issue is I can't use any russian symbols in the `response()->json()` method.
I've already tried the following code:

```
return response()->json(['users' => 'тест']);

and

return response()->json(['users' => mb_convert_encoding('тест', 'UTF-8')]);

and

return response()->json(
       ['users' => mb_convert_encoding('тест', 'UTF-8')])
       ->header('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

I've checked the default encoding:

```
mb_detect_encoding('тест'); // returns 'UTF-8'
```

Also, all my files have been converter to UTF-8 without BOM. I've added the default character set to the .htaccess file(`AddDefaultCharset utf-8`) as well.

But, I still get the wrong response like here:

```
{"users":"\u0442\u0435\u0441\u0442"}
```

Comment: Why do you think it's wrong response?

Comment: I mean it's wrong for me)). I expect `{'users': 'тест'}`

Comment: `u0442` is a unicode representation of `т`

Comment: Cool! But, I hope I don't convert all unicode symbols to russian manually. I want to use something like this `json_encode(['users', 'тест'], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)`

Comment: Probably, it isn't completely correct, but this code `return response()->make(json_encode(['users' => 'тест'], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE))->header('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');` has solved my issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The response that you are getting:

```
 {"users":"\u0442\u0435\u0441\u0442"}
```

is valid JSON!

That being said, if you don't want to encode the UTF-8 characters, you can simply just do this:

```
 $data = [ 'users' => 'тест' ];
 $headers = [ 'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8' ];

 return response()->json($data, 200, $headers, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

The output would then be

```
 {"users":"тест"}
```

## Why does this work?

Calling the `response()` helper will create an instance of `Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory`. `ResponseFactory`'s `json` function has the following signature:

`public function json($data = [], $status = 200, array $headers = [], $options = 0)`

Calling `json()` will create a new instance of `Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse`, which will be the class responsible for running `json_encode` for your data. Inside the `setData` function in `JsonResponse`, your array will be encoded with the `$options` provided on the `response()->json(...)` call:

```
 json_encode($data, $this->jsonOptions);
```

As you can see on the [documentation on php.net for the `json_encode` function](http://php.net/json_encode) and the [documentation on php.net for the `json_encode` Predefined Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php), **`JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`** will encode multibyte Unicode characters literally (default is to escape as \uXXXX).

It is important to note that `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` has only been supported since PHP 5.4.0, so make sure you are running 5.4.0 or newer to use this.

Comment: Lumen does not work with php < 5.4, it probably required the 5.5.9 from the start (although the composer constraint was added only recently)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @timgws! It's the really nice answer!

Comment: @tacone you are correct that lumen does not work with PHP >= 5.5.9, but the note for PHP < 5.4.0 is related to json_encode, and not directly for the Laravel framework.